# LRT for a Linear Mixed Model

Tags: glmm, degrees-of-freedom

I want to compare the likelihoods for a model with population structure (a mixed effect represented by a variance-covariance matrix) to one without population structure (represented by an identity matrix). This would not change the predictor value or the covariates, just the k-matrix.

Is there a way to tell how many degrees of freedom this change would represent? I would like to treat the no-structure example as my null hypothesis.